# How to correctly process index dependencies for correct language?

Tags: solr, indexing

I am updating index dependencies as mentioned in 
[Sitecore Full Content Search](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8976/sitecore-full-content-search) where we are using `GetDatasourceDependencies`.

Now, the issue is that this works fine for the English language, but, whenever I publish content for a non-English version, it's still taking dependency in the English version, but the dependency for published item is actually in a non-English version. where as Item object is in fr-FR version as returned by this piece of code  Item item = (Item)(context.IndexedItem as SitecoreIndexableItem);
it's dependency is still returned in English version i think last two lines of processor need to pass language code some where but not sure where

My Pipeline code is like this:

```
public class GetDatasourceDependencies : BaseProcessor
{
    public override void Process(GetDependenciesArgs context)
    {
        Func<ItemUri, bool> func = null;
        Assert.IsNotNull(context.IndexedItem, "indexed item");
        Assert.IsNotNull(context.Dependencies, "dependencies");
        Item item = (Item)(context.IndexedItem as SitecoreIndexableItem);

        if (item != null)
        {
            if (func == null)
            {
                func = uri => (bool)((uri != null) && ((bool)(uri != item.Uri)));
            }
            System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ItemUri> source = Enumerable.Where<ItemUri>(from l in Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item, FieldIDs.LayoutField) select l.GetSourceItem().Uri, func).Distinct<ItemUri>();
            context.Dependencies.AddRange(source.Select(x => (SitecoreItemUniqueId)x));
        }
    }
}
```

How to correctly process index dependencies for correct language?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Even though my Item in this code `Item item = (Item)(context.IndexedItem as SitecoreIndexableItem);` is of fr-FR version it's still returning dependency in English version

Comment: I think there we need to do some modification in these two lines of code . But not sure where System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ItemUri> source = Enumerable.Where<ItemUri>(from l in Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item, FieldIDs.LayoutField) select l.GetSourceItem().Uri, func).Distinct<ItemUri>();
            context.Dependencies.AddRange(source.Select(x => (SitecoreItemUniqueId)x));

Comment: Note that you can edit your question to add more details if you want.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to include the `Final Layout` field as well. The `Final Layout` field will differ per version of your item, i.e. a different language. The primary `Layout` field is set to `[shared]`, which means it's *shared* across languages.

```
public override void Process(GetDependenciesArgs context)
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(context.IndexedItem, "indexed item");
    Assert.IsNotNull(context.Dependencies, "dependencies");

    var item = (Item)(context.IndexedItem as SitecoreIndexableItem);

    if (item == null)
        return;

    bool Func(ItemUri uri) => (uri != null) && uri != item.Uri;

    var source = (
        from l 
            in Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item, FieldIDs.LayoutField)
        select l.GetSourceItem().Uri)
            .Where(Func)
            .ToList();

    // this is what you're missing
    source.AddRange(
    (
        from l
            in Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item, FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField)
        select l.GetSourceItem().Uri)
            .Where(Func)
    );

    source = source.DistinctBy(i => i.ItemID).ToList();

    context.Dependencies.AddRange(source.Select(x => (SitecoreItemUniqueId)x));
}
```

The extension `DistinctBy()` is listed below:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Filters items out of a collection that have distinct key values. Key values are determined by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">Type of the enumerable object</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">Type of the keys</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The items to select from</param>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A function to select key values</param>
    /// <returns>The items that have distinct key values</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        var seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        return source.Where(element => seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)));
    }
}
```

Comment: For consideration of search we are only taking renderings added on Shared layout final layout is not considered at all . If i remove the  final layout code snippet from your solution Will i be able to get right dependency

Comment: Why aren't you considering the `Final Layout`? What exactly are you trying to index?

Comment: We are indexing everything on shared layout since all the content Authoring is taking place on shared layout only.

Comment: For that to be the case, your authors would need to work exclusively in Content Editor, is this the case? Also, how are you versioning EN content from FR? Again, the `Shared Layout` is _shared_ so if an item has a version in EN and FR and you make a change in either language version, both language versions will get the change. Do you have separate tree structures for EN vs FR?

Comment: if an item has a version in EN and FR since it's shared layout we are fine for both language version to get change since content and look and feel will not vary across languages

Comment: It's sounding like your issue isn't pertaining to `indexing.getDependencies`, but instead elsewhere, possibly where you're executing the query.

Comment: Which query are referring can you please help me point to exact issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73585/discussion-between-jrap-and-user2332873).

Comment: Can we have a chat same time tomorrow

Comment: Guys- Can some one provide further help on this